# Getting unexpected result when adding json:Array attribute to an xml node before serializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net, handlebars.js

I have an XML document that I need to serialize into JSON.  I had everything working (or so I thought) until my handlebars.js was failing on the "each" expression.  I have narrowed the problem down to my xml > json conversion using JSON.NET.  Elements that can sometimes have multiple children are rendering as single elements (not arrays) when converting to json.  The documentation states that I have to add an attribute to the node (json:Array="true") for it to always render as an array (which would no longer break my handlebars).

The first thing I do is add the namespace to my XML document (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json).

Then I am iterating through each node and testing it to see if its one that I need to be array'd then add the attribute.

```
//Pseudo code
foreach(XmlNode node in list)
{
    XmlAttribute attr = originalDoc.CreateAttribute(@"json:Array");
    if(node.Name == "needsToBeAnArray")
    {
        node.Attributes.Append(attr);
    }
}
```

I then save the doc to a memory stream and reload it into a new XmlDocument object.

The resulting json I am getting however looks like this:

```
{"@Array":"true","item":[{"subitem":"foo", "subitem2":"foo2"}]}
```

From my understanding of the JSON.NET docs, it should just render as an array (not show this "@Array" thing).  Does anyone have and experience with this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the `json` prefix is getting stripped off the `json:Array` attribute when you add it to the node, since it is not qualified with a namespace.  Without the `json` prefix, the attribute has no special meaning to Json.Net; thus, it gets written into the JSON instead of changing the output behavior.

Try it like this instead:

```
string xml =
    @"<person>
      <name>Joe</name>
      <age>28</age>
      <role>Admin</role>
    </person>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    if (node.Name == "role")
    {
        XmlAttribute att = doc.CreateAttribute("json", "Array", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json");
        att.Value = "true";
        node.Attributes.Append(att);
    }
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "person": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": "28",
    "role": [
      "Admin"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Where were you an hour ago Brian ;)

Comment: LOL, trying to figure out why it wasn't working for you  ;-)  Looks like we were both working in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong if anyone is interested.  When I was creating the attribute:

```
XmlAttribute attr = originalDoc.CreateAttribute(@"json:Array");
```

I was trying to name it with my prefix.  The proper way to do this is to pass in the prefix, name and namespace as the parameters.

```
XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("json", "Array", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json");
```